# filter operation in html table angularjs or server side

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sql-server

Our Project deals with huge records, we are using normal table but showing only less number of records to user. that means we have 15 million records in back-end but showing only 1000 records to user.

If user want to search the specific records then they can use filter operation. We have implemented filter functionality in angularjs, i.e. created custom services to do filter operation for large records. the problem is we are keeping the huge records in $scope variable.

```
//$scope.filteredVldData is a array which  contains 15 million records.
 var result = filterService.filter($scope.filteredVldData);

//Filter Service

var filterApp = angular.module('filterModule', []);
filterApp.factory('filterService', function () {
    return {
        filter: function (filterData) {

//For Equals logic

//For not equals logic

//For Contains logic
            }
}});
```

filter operation is working fine. It is giving desired result. I am not sure whether it is good way of keeping 15 million records in clients side  $scope variable to perform filter operation.

Each record having 15  columns so am keeping huge size of records in client side.

Because of huge volume of records, I am planning to move the filter logic in server side, whenever filter applied it will go to back-end and get the result bind to the table.

Which one is best way to do filter operation in normal html table  when considering millions of records ? either in client side or server side ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the size of that record and what kind of hardware your client will be using. For normal personal computers/laptops as a client it's always good to have the filter/sort operation done on the server side and only display viable subset of records needed to be displayed.

Another point is - if your client side has a local storage system and you need offline data search/viewing, then probably you can do a sync initially to store the data on the local storage (again, if that's not huge for the client ) and then filter and retrieve only subset to memory and display.

Comment: yes you are  right!! the record is large only(15  columns per record) so for 15 million records it will be huge. Then in that case can we go ahead to do the filter operation in back-end like stored procedure ?

Comment: Ideally Yes. You should go ahead. Also total storage size depends on type and size of each field of a record, for text data it would take small disk space. The issue is bigger when it comes to process those quickly and return result. The processing of all those 15 million records will take huge time if the processor and memory is less (and it would be same slow if the server configuration is low ).